# which server I should go for JBoss or GlassFish

Tags: jboss5.x, application-server, glassfish-3

I am project I will be using following tech. JSF 2.0, Hibernate, Spring, jBPM, JAX-WS so I am confused between chosing server and I am locked between JBoss and GlassFish please suggest me why I should use the one. I will be using Netbeans 6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From a Development Perspective:**

If you are using NetBeans then I think the easiest to integrate with will be GlassFish, simply because they come both from Sun and you will get the **best out-of-the-box experience**. While not mandatory, the Java EE Tutorial from Sun also emphasizes the use of NetBeans with GlassFish.

Nonetheless if you happen to use JBoss, it won't be difficult to integrate it on NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

**From a Deployment and Long-term Maintenance Perspective:**

See [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949370/glassfish-appserver-or-jboss-appserver-which-is-more-better-for-production-envir/18538479#18538479).