# Glassfish AppServer or JBoss AppServer which is better for Production Environment?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, jboss7.x, application-server

I would like to know about pros and cons of glassfish server and jboss 
(glassfish v3 vs jboss 7.0) in using in production environment, i know more people use jboss as the application server, but glassfish has more features and stability over jboss
do you agree with me?

Comment: I can't comment on JBoss, but we run a clustered Glassfish in production without any issues (for the past 3 years).

Comment: +1 for saying "more better".  lol

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/oracle-glassfish-server/comparing-glassfish-jboss-wp-117118.pdf

Answer (score 13):

Ask the question on the GlassFish forums and you'll get GlassFish as an answer.  Ask the question on the JBoss forums and you'll get JBoss as an answer. Ask here, and you'll likely get both :-)

**Stability.** I can tell you that the amount of testing we put into GlassFish Server Open Source Edition is substantial - it has the same high quality as the commercial version (Oracle GlassFish Server) when released, although the commercial version ships patches more regularly.  According to JBoss (and someone correct me if I am wrong), JBoss does not do their full quality testing on the open source bits - full QA is only on their commercial distributions (JBoss Enterprise Application Platform). I can't say with any empirical evidence which open source appserver has better quality, but the approach to quality for the open source distributions are very different between the two.

**Features.** IMHO, GlassFish has a more mature and feature rich administration console, command line tool (useful for automation), and RESTful administration and monitoring API.  The former two have been available in GlassFish since before 2005 when the Sun appserver was open-sourced as GlassFish, the RESTful API since 2008.

FYI, I am the GlassFish Server product manager, so I am heavily biased :-)

Hope this helps and please let us all know what you finally decide and why.

Thanks.

Comment: I just want to update those who still googles "GlassFish vs JBOSS" and did not follow the news (like myself) about the end of commercial support for **GlassFish**. If you are considering possible need for future commercial support, choose **JBOSS** platform (to be specific, **WildFly** as JBOSS'es application server called now).

Answer (score 5):

The team responsible for JRebel has done [a small comparison/evaluation here](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-with-tomcat-jboss-glassfish-jetty-and-liberty-profile/).

My company switched a tertiary care hospital (12,000 employees) from running several of its electronic services from WebSphere to Glassfish. Massive savings in licensing costs, and very high stability.

However, I think there is one area that Glassfish is truly amazing in, and its something not many people emphasize. The JRebel comparison mentions it, but does not give it nearly enough weight. Most people look at application servers from a development and performance perspective... and most application servers are "good enough" in that area nowadays (again, see the JRebel comparison).

But one feature requires a lot of time to develop, and isn't something that can be done overnight, it really requires an architectural decision very early on. And it's something that was definitely built in from the beginning in Glassfish's roots (Sun Application Server). I'm talking about **the ability to control the server purely and entirely using a command line interface**. This is an enormous advantage. It allows us to build scripts for automating everything across a farm of clustered servers (we have nearly 15 now). And I mean *everything*. We use Jenkins (Hudson) to run those scripts, and it is truly an elegant, integrated solution.

This isn't because we're a smart company - far from it. Glassfish just makes it easy to do. The command line interface is worth tens of thousands of saved dollars over time, more and more every day.