# Glassfish - Pros and Cons

Tags: java, glassfish

I've entered a project where glassfish was chosen as the appserver before I came on. I haven't heard of many people using glassfish on production, as it's really meant now as just the reference implementation of jee7, so I'm suspicious. Also there's been rumors that Oracle will phase glassfish out, they're already not doing support for it.

Can anybody give me the reasons to use glassfish or not, or more specifically what should I consider in my decision whether to keep it? As I understand it, glassfish has tomcat as the web container, so maybe it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: isn't it more important how your teammates justify their decision?

Comment: Did you search StackOverflow for pros and cons?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949370/glassfish-appserver-or-jboss-appserver-which-is-more-better-for-production-envir

will point you to 
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-with-tomcat-jboss-glassfish-jetty-and-liberty-profile/

Comment: @GREnvoy thanks for the link. The SO question and the ZeroTurnAround study are from 2013. I looked around ZeroTurnaround some more and the next year they came out with this: http://pages.zeroturnaround.com/RebelLabs-AllReportLanders_MigratingfromGlassFish.html?utm_source=Migrating%20from%20GlassFish&utm_medium=allreports&utm_campaign=rebellabs&utm_rebellabsid=85  essentially saying glassfish was dead and detailing how to migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strongest points for Glassfish are that it is open-source and that it already supports Java EE 7, as it is the reference implementation. It also has user-friendly administration console, which used to be a killer feature too. Nowadays, the project is a bit slow to fix bugs, although there is a supported version of Glassfish called [Payara](http://www.payara.fish) with many bug fixes and additional features, even with a micro version for development of microservices.

Nowadays, I would not recommend to run a new project on Glassfish, especially as there is equally open-source version by Payara with lots of fixes and optional prduction support. Although there are few open-source alternatives for Glassfish, [WildFly](http://wildfly.org) seems to be very promising, as it is backed by Red Hat and has a big comumnity behind. [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) is also a nice alternative, but it still does not support  Java EE 7, although it is very close to support it.

Comment: I am leaning towards WildFly or JBoss. I need to investigate Payara more.

Comment: WildFly would be a good choice, JBoss makes sense only in case you need commercial support. In case it is hard to switch from Glassfish or you would like to stay with a Glassfish-like server, Payara is a great choice too. Have a look a their site [www.payara.fish](http://www.payara.fish) and also at the [Payara github repository](https://github.com/payara/Payara) with all the sources. Payara comes in free open-source version with regular bug-fix releases and it is also possible to get paid commercial support, which is probably cheaper than support for JBoss by RedHat.